# HTML5 way to store/retrieve object's data

Tags: html, jquery-data

what's the HTML5 replacement (pure HTML no jQuery) for the following?

```
$("#blah#").data("key", value);
var value = $("#blah#").data("key");
```

Comment: <div id="blah" data-key="value"></div>

Comment: You cannot replace jQuery with HTML. You can with Javascript.

Comment: @r043v how's bout JSON objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('data-key', 'value');
var value = document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('data-key');
```

Comment: will that support JSON/JS objects?

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage` to achieve your criteria.

### Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('XYZ', value);

// Retrieve the object from storage
var value = localStorage.getItem('XYZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `localstorage` or `sessionstorage` depending on the lifetime you want to give to the datas.

Data placed in `Local Storage` is per domain (it's available to all scripts from the domain that originally stored the data) and persists after the browser is closed.

`Session Storage` is per-page-per-window and is limited to the lifetime of the window. `Session Storage` is intended to allow separate instances of the same web application to run in different windows without interfering with each other.

**Session Storage :**

```
<!-- Store value on browser for duration of the session -->
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

<!-- Retrieve value (gets deleted when browser is closed and re-opened) -->
alert(sessionStorage.getItem('key'));
```

**Local Storage :**

```
<!-- Store value on the browser beyond the duration of the session -->
localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

<!-- Retrieve value (works even after closing and re-opening the browser) -->
alert(localStorage.getItem('key'));
```

Mind the minimum version for that :

http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage